# OCMockito: RACObserve a mocked object always fail

Tags: reactive-cocoa, ocmockito

code like this:

```
@implementation MyClass

- (void)func
{
//MyOtherClassObject is an object passed in when initialising MyClass
    NSArray *signals = @[[RACObserve(MyOtherClassObject, prop) subscribeNext:^{{}]];
}

@end

@implementation MyTest

- (void)testSomething
{
    MyOtherClass *mock = mock([MyOtherClass class]);
    MyClass *myObject = [[MyClass alloc] initWithOtherObject:mock]
    [myObject func];  //this won't work since RACObserve will return nil instead of a valid signal
}

@end
```

So, is there any way I can get a mocked object RACObserved like normal object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because OCMockito (and OCMock as well) breaks Key-Value Observing, that is, you won't get any KVO "callbacks" from the mocked objects. And `RACObserve` uses KVO under the hood. 
There are many possible workarounds:

1. As described in OCMockito docs:

> How do you stub a property so that KVO works? Use
>   stubProperty(instance, property, value). For example:

```
stubProperty(mockEmployee, firstName, @"fake-firstname");
```

I haven't used OCMockito so I can't tell whether this will really work with RAC.

2. Use a *real* object instead of a mock. It will work for some cases (when the object is really simple and you just need to change a property). Of course it shouldn't be used when it will break isolation of the unit test (for example, by sending a network request or accessing a database / file system).
3. Extract the signal returned by `RACObserve` to a property and stub. Instead of

`NSArray *signals = @[[RACObserve(MyOtherClassObject, prop) subscribeNext:^{{}]];`

do:

`NSArray *signals = MyOtherClassObject.prop`

where `MyOtherClassObject.prop` will return `RACObserve(self, prop)`. 
Then you can easily stub `MyOtherClassObject.prop` and return any signal,
for example `[RACSignal return:]` for getting a single value synchronously.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I think stubbing the signal getter is a brilliant idea

Comment: by the way, stubProperty doesn't work since it only fakes the getter and setter, but RAC retrieve by using objc_getProperties